# Lock Issue in Snowflake while inserting data from pyspark dataframe

Tags: pyspark, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to insert a pyspark dataframe to a snowflake table with the help of following code:

```
sfOptions = {
  "sfURL" : "XXXXXXXXXXXX",
  "sfAccount" : "XXXXXXXXXXXX",
  "sfUser" : "XXXXXXXXXXXX",
  "sfPassword" : "XXXXXXXXXXXX",
  "sfDatabase" : "XXXXXXXXXXXX",
  "sfSchema" : "XXXXXXXXXXXX",
  "sfWarehouse" : "XXXXXXXXXXXX",
  "sfRole" : "XXXXXXXXXXXX",
  "column_mapping" : "name",
  "column_mismatch_behavior":"ignore"
    }
  
df.write.format("snowflake") \
              .options(**sfOptions) \
              .option("dbtable", table).mode("append").save()
```

I am successfully able to insert the data to the table with the help of above code.
But when i am trying to do the same operation in multi-threading I am getting the below error:

> y4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o146688.save.
> : net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeSQLException: Statement '019fce57-0b02-036b-0000-467d0010e94a' has locked table 'ERROR_RECORDS' in transaction 1635015824820 and this lock has not yet been released.
> Your statement '019fce57-0b02-036b-0000-467d0010e9f2' was aborted because the number of waiters for this lock exceeds the 20 statements limit.

I am not able to hit the method concurrently please do let me know any suggestions.

Comment: Could you share a little bit about your use-case here?  Are you simply trying to load data faster or does your application have multiple concurrent users that are all trying to insert data into the same table at the same time?

Comment: How many threads?

Answer (score 1):

There is a *soft* limit for the maximum number of waiters to acquire a lock on a resource (table/micro-partition). As the message indicates, you are hitting this limit (20).

So the question is, why are there 20+ sessions trying to modify the same table in a data warehouse environment? From your question, I assume that you try to increase the parallelism by multi-threading. IMO, you should use one single spark job, and let the Snowflake handle the parallelism when ingesting the data.

It's also possible to increase this limit if you contact Snowflake Support, but that will only make things worst because that will not increase parallelism, it will only enable more sessions to wait.

https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/Your-statement-was-aborted-because-the-number-of-waiters-for-this-lock-exceeds-the-20-statements-limit

Comment: the link is broken now, u got any other alike reference ?

Comment: @Gokhan Atil ,the link is broken ,please provide alternate link

Comment: @ays1 The document is removed because it is recommended to fix the architecture instead of increasing the queue size. As I explained, increasing the limit doesn't increase concurrency - it will enable more queries to pile up without getting an error. You can still submit a support ticket for this limit.